# solve in terms of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I need the full solution (with steps) of $K^4=-4$. 
First, I tried to solve in termes of $K^2$ and I tried to include in my answer the j term of complex numbers.

Thanks

Comment: So what was $K^2$?  Do you know what squared gives $j=\sqrt{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are:
$$
-4=4\cdot(-1)=4e^{i(\pi+2k\pi)}\;,\;k\in\mathbb Z\;.
$$
so
$$
z^4=-4\Leftrightarrow z^4=4e^{i(\pi+2k\pi)}
$$
from which you get the solution:
$$
z_k=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac\pi{4}+ik\frac\pi{4}}.
$$
Observing that as $k\in\mathbb Z$, the different solutions will be only four, so you can consider $z_k$ for $k=0,1,2,3$.